# overriding body wide css setting for a dojo content pane

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a `jsp` file with a `dojo` widget inside the `body` which results in a popup dialog box.

```
<body class="myBody">
        // my widget goes here
</body>
```

My `dojo` widgets `html` has

```
 class="myWidget"
```

just as a placeholder.

In the `css` file for this `jsp`, I have

```
.myBody .dijitContentPane {
       padding-bottom: 0 !important;
 }
```

So this is applicable to all `dijitContentPanes` inside the `body` of `jsp`.

However, I want to override this for `myWidget`. For `myWidget`, instead of `padding-bottom` as `0`, I want it as `20px`.

How can I achieve this? I want to keep the generic setting above as is. But I don't want to apply it to `myWidget`.

Comment: try to apply inline styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has a :not(x) selector. Does that fit in with what you need, by changing your selector to

```
.myBody .dijitContentPane:not(.myWidget) {
   padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

?

The following worked:

```
.myBody .dijitContentPane:not(myWidget.) {
   padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: oh, I think I made a mistake in the example - don't know if you tried :not(.myWidget) or :not(myWidget), the first one is the "correct" version